# Why won't the color of the fog change according to the ClockTime in Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a script where if the ClockTime is over 7, it changes the color of the Fog and Ambient Light. Unfortunately, something seems to be wrong and it just won't change. What am I doing wrong?

This is my first day trying to script so I'm happy to get advice

[image: The Script]

```
local ClockTime = 0
Time = game.Lighting.ClockTime
while true do 

    if Time > 7 then
    game.Lighting.FogColor = Color3.fromRGB(111, 181, 254)
    game.Lighting.FogEnd = 5000
    game.Lighting.FogStart = 0
    game.Lighting.OutdoorAmbient = Color3.fromRGB (179, 195, 232)

    elseif Time > 18 then
    game.Lighting.FogColor = Color3.fromRGB(0, 0, 0)
    game.Lighting.FogEnd = 5000
    game.Lighting.FogStart = 0
    game.Lighting.OutdoorAmbient = Color3.fromRGB (42, 43, 59)
    end

end
```

Text in case you need it

Answer (score 0):

The condition `Time > 18` is also true for `Time > 7` check. So it falls into the first branch, never reaching the second one.

Change the order in which you test the time. Test for `Time > 18` first, and then test for `Time > 7`

Comment: @마미르 It seems the `Time` doesn't change either, because it's outside of the loop. Move it within the loop.

Comment: Just moved it within the loop, still doesn't change

Comment: Ah, I think I have a solution. It must be because of the other script that handles the time

Comment: Btw, isn't your script just timed out, because it spins in a loop without any kind of relinquishing controls back to roblox?

Comment: So I've added a script the makes the time reset to 0 once it goes over 24. Sadly, it still won't work

Comment: Is your time changes at all? Some other script properly updates your `game.Lighting.ClockTime`, and it's changing fast enough to see the updates in fog?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I was using 2 separate scripts at once. Once I merged those 2 scripts, it is now working fine.